# change input type date format

Tags: php, date, datepicker

I am using bootstrap date picker.Here is my code

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="dateFrom"  name="dateFrom" required parsley-maxlength="6" placeholder="From Date" />
</div>
```

Here date format displays in the text field by selecting date in datepicker as mm/dd/yyyy.
Is there have any way to change the input type date format to dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: You could use data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"

Comment: how can we use it as an input type

Comment: Like this?: <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="dateFrom"  name="dateFrom" required parsley-maxlength="6" placeholder="From Date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" />

Comment: But its not working

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

```
$('#dateFrom').datepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
 });
```